# Permanent ON/OFF tactile switch

Tags: switches, components

I am looking for a small tactile switch that works like:

press once -> turn on, press again -> turn off

I only found this model http://www.adafruit.com/products/1683 , but i am looking to buy directly from manufacturer/reference in mouser or digikey if possible, for a small production batch

do you know how can i find this?

Comment: also see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic ... shopping questions are expressly not on-topic

Comment: What you're describing is called `Alternate Action` switch. See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/141663/push-button-switch-terminology

Comment: Component selection, IMHO, is an integral part of engineering.  I don't see why it would be considered off-topic.

Comment: I was looking for names, references, etc, but i couldn't find any one (i am not english native)

Answer (score 0):

Searching for on/off pushbuttons with PC pin termination on digikey: http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv258=60&FV=fff40011%2Cfff80061%2C3ac0009%2C3ac0011&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25

A couple of the results are very similar to the adafruit component.