# How to distinguish which buttons have fixed on/off positions similar to a flashlight button?

Tags: switches, components, button

I'm searching for a button/switch similar to one on a common flashlight: you click the button to turn the light on, then eventually click it again to turn off. [Example clip of Button (Adafruit / YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zzhqn1K7OwQ&t=257s).

The only one I can find on Mouser/Digikey is by Adafruit/overpriced. I'm sure there are more like this but looking through many datasheets I have no way of what is a basic button and what has fixed on/off states like the Adafruit switch/button.

How can I find/filter/distinguish buttons with fixed on/off positions? (I'm looking for surface mount with a small package size to be specific).

[image: Adafruit button/switch with on/off positions]

Comment: That video was difficult to watch for me. The speaker struggled with saying even so much as "single pole" and almost certainly had zero clues about the life experiences of the audience she was targeting with her sales pitch. The audience was demeaned by the quality of the individual they chose to present the product. What you may be looking for is a self-locking or self-latching SPST push button.

Comment: (Or, as I'm finding, sometimes also called SPDT even when it's not.)

Comment: A button that doesn't maintain its state after pressing is *momentary*. I don't know if there's a word for what you're looking for other than "not momentary".

Comment: Thanks for the help, still searching! @ThePhoton "not momentary" is "maintained
 action (locking)" according to this datasheet [MHPS Switches](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/APEM%20Components%20PDFs/MHPS_Series.pdf) - which is the single button I've found so far which is clear about this (this specific button won't work for me unfortunately). Still a great datasheet compared to the rest - even details at what stages the button makes a click sound.

Comment: @jonk In the extremely fast-growing "maker" community, companies like Adafruit have found a niche in providing electronic parts and kits to a customer base that's unfortunately often ignorant of a lot of basic EE terminology. Limor Fried (the owner of Adafruit and speaker in the linked video), I believe is extremely knowledgeable and skilled, including being able to "dumb down" the explanation of products to a low common denominator (sometimes to a painful degree).

Comment: @JYelton Sure was difficult to see that stumble. But it was the "shopping channel" approach to selling that pretty much turned me off, regardless of her skills. I will probably now never buy from Adafruit, just as a matter of principle. I hate that kind of selling technique and I certainly won't lend my support to it.

Comment: Related: "Alternate Action" pushbutton switch - https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/141663/push-button-switch-terminology

Comment: @jonk That's unfortunate but I support your decision. When it comes to the tutorials and write-ups that document such things as Arduino and Raspberry Pi projects on their site, Limor has generally done a terrific job of explaining everything from wiring to coding in a way that helps lure in absolute beginners. I'm grateful such resources exist, but also sometimes annoyed at the "shopping channel" approach!

Comment: @JYelton I also respect what you say and I can gather up that perspective, as well. I am also pleased they have and continue to make resources that others can use for their own purposes, so readily. I just have a violent reactions to "shopping channel" approaches to a public and have made the choice to reduce consumption from anyone employing them (for any reason.) Thanks, though, for the added information about the individual. I've adjusted my thoughts there, as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at switches and buttons, you'll find a wide variety of terms to describe the switch action. Further, those terms will vary a little bit based on the type of switch as well. For example, it would be more common to see "latching" or "on/off" with a pushbutton switch, but not a rocker or toggle. Slide switches, which are *typically* not momentary, even have momentary versions, making it a vendor's decision whether or not to label the "normal" ones somehow.

Let's take a look at pushbutton switches at two popular vendors, Digikey and Mouser:

- **Digikey**:

  [image: Digikey "Switch Function" filter]

  Any position on a switch that's momentary is denoted by the "Mom" abbreviation in the list. A pushbutton in the style you're looking for would then be found under the "Off-On" category. Here, "On" would mean it stays in that position, because otherwise they would use "Mom" to indicate that position is momentary.

  Also note that "Off-Mom" and "On-Mom" would help distinguish what the switch does by default. The first being "off unless pushed" and the second being "on unless pushed."
- **Mouser**:

  [image: Mouser "Switch Function" filter]

  Mouser uses parenthesis to indicate momentary positions. So "(ON)" here is the same as "Mom" above. They've also kind of went a bit overboard (IMO) and show the reciprocal function in some cases, so "OFF - ON, ON - OFF" just means you could have either position be off or on, depending on how you wire it. (This is the same as "OFF - ON" but my guess is manufacturer-provided data gets put into more than one category that should otherwise be combined.)

  The number of poles (or common terminals) on a switch may also have something to do with unusual switch action filter options.

---

The switch you refer to is small, but I wouldn't call it surface mount. The tabs are certainly something you *could* surface mount if desired, but it appears to be a very small *panel mount* switch. Some panel mount switches have flanges or threads to mount through some sort of enclosure wall, others may have holes to allow mounting via screws, and still others (like the one you show) may just use a bit of glue or some sort of friction fit. An actual surface-mount/tactile switch (at least the ones I can find) is almost always momentary.

Adafruit provides the [datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/3870/3870_datasheet.pdf) (or [this](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Adafruit%20PDFs/3870_Web.pdf)) to their switch, but that probably doesn't help you source them. The closest I could find on Digikey is a [Judco 40-4911-00](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Judco%20PDFs/40-4911-00.pdf). All that said, good quality switches can be expensive. If you're finding the Adafruit switch to be too expensive at USD $0.95 each, then you're not likely to find a better price unless you inquire about quantity discounts.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful - the Judco switch might work for me! I guess theses latch type buttons aren't as common as I would've thought. And to clarify about the Adafruit price, I didn't mean expensive as in per switch, I meant as in the exact same are only pennies on AliExpress (I bought some in the past for a handheld laser repair). Thanks for the clarification, I'll do a little more digging! Also the "Off - On" (or opposite) filters aren't the best unfortunately - tons of incorrectly labeled results.

Comment: @AugustKimo Yep, unfortunately whoever's job it is to create those search filters has a difficult task! Manufacturers never agree on terminology and certainly don't put it in the same place in their datasheets. Searching for components and parts involves a bit of ingenuity and persistence. Good luck.